# Cant use images from public folder Next.js 14 Page router, upstream image response failed for

Tags: reactjs, next.js14

Can't import images from the public folder on my Next.js project if using  component from next/image, but it works with HTML .
I receive error:
upstream image response failed for /_next/static/media/tata-logo.f365d74f.png

I am using page router, Next.js v14, react 18.2.

I was migrating Next from v12 to v14 this is next.config.js
This is my react component for displaying the public image, I tried static import and describing a path in it.

```
import tenantLogo from 'public/tenants/base/icons/tata-logo.png';

...

      <Image
        src={tenantLogo}
        alt={t('common:alt.logo')}
        width={getLogoWidth()}
        height={getLogoHeight()}
        objectFit="contain"
      />
...
```

Also this is my next.config.js

```
// This file sets a custom webpack configuration to use your Next.js app
// with Sentry.
// https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction
// https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/manual-setup/
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const { withSentryConfig } = require('@sentry/nextjs');

/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');
const withReactSvg = require('next-react-svg');
const path = require('path');
const withPWA = require('next-pwa');
const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
});

/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const defaultConfig = {
  swcMinify: true,
  include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/icons'),
  webpack(config) {
    return config;
  },
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: '**',
      },
    ],
  },
  i18n,
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true, // CI runs linting before build
  },
  typescript: {
    ignoreBuildErrors: true, // CI runs type-checking before build
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    appEnv: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ENV,
    clientTenantSecrets: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_TENANT_SECRETS,
  },
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    tenantSecrets: process.env.TENANT_SECRETS,
  },
  sentry: {
    hideSourcemaps: true,
  },
};

const hocs = [
  {
    hoc: withPWA,
    props: {
      pwa: {
        dest: 'public',
        disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
        register: true,
        sw: 'service-worker.js',
        mode: 'production',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    hoc: withReactSvg,
    props: {},
  },
  {
    hoc: withBundleAnalyzer,
    props: {},
  },
];
const configWithHocs = hocs.reduce(
  (accumulator, hocConfig) =>
    hocConfig.hoc({ ...accumulator, ...hocConfig.props }),
  defaultConfig,
);

module.exports = withSentryConfig(
  configWithHocs,
  {
    silent: true,
    authToken: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,
  },
  { hideSourcemaps: true },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are encountering the error: "upstream image response failed for /_next/static/media/tata-logo.f365d74f.png", because the way you are importing the image is not correct.

You should use here the "relative path referencing". here is the example of this:

```
import feedbackImage from '../../public/images/feedback.jpg'
```

in the above code i am using the "relative path referencing" way to import the image and i am adding this from the src/pages/api/index.js.

Have a nice day.